# Direct to s3 / client file uploads. Is there a concern for storing unused files in your s3 bucket with this approach?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I was looking over this tutorial suggested by heroku (for NodeJs apps) for signing the s3 file via the server, then handling the upload directly from the client:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node

I wonder about the potential of many unused files being stored in your s3 bucket.

In the heroku tutorial, they run through a user-edit scenario. They state :

- > When a user selects an image to be uploaded, the upload to S3 is
  >   handled automatically and asynchronously with the process described
  >   earlier in this article. The image preview is then updated with the
  >   selected image once the upload is complete and successful.
- > The user then clicks the “submit” button, which posts the username,
  >   name and the URL of the uploaded image to the Node application to be
  >   checked and/or stored. If no image was uploaded by the user earlier
  >   the default avatar image URL is posted instead.

So, what if the user selects the image, then clicks to another page without finishing and submitting the user-profile information?

Is that just a wasted file stored in your s3 bucket?

---

I"m using a similar approach in my MEAN app, where on submit:

- I upload the file to S3.
- Then, with a promise, once the upload completes, I submit the user's 
  profile information / post with the s3 url to the server.

I had a similar concern, what if the user leaves before the promise invokes or there is a connection issue -- is there a concern of storing unused files?

Is this the typical way of handling this, and that's just part of the risk?

Comment: We put uploads in one bucket with a seven-day automatic deletion retention policy. Upon successful submission, we move it to the permanent bucket. Works nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the upload is occurring client side doesn't make this problem any more or less worse than if you did it server side.  You still need a mechanism of handling errors and keeping things in sync with your database.

How you handle this depends on your specific application needs.  @ceejayoz mentioned one method of having a temporary bucket.  I prefer to not worry about the upload until it's done, handling the data update with a Lambda job.  You could also have a sync process with list operations if you really wanted to, but I think that's typically unnecessary.